# Issues with the sidebar ads

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, advertising

[We have issues http://img237.imageshack.us/img237/7923/firefoxscreensnapz001.jpg](http://img237.imageshack.us/img237/7923/firefoxscreensnapz001.jpg)

Not sure what to make of this, but it's been going on for the past hour or so, on and off.

Comment: Your circles are neither red nor hand drawn. Something is wrong with the universe.

Comment: Confirmed on my end. It should also be noted that the careers box is displaying buttons instead of text.

Comment: @Andrew: Actually, it is hand drawn, and the selected color *was* red.

Comment: The freehand circle thing was much funnier before people felt the need to comment on it every time it happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We disabled the ads for now until the careers team is in the office and can deal with it.