# Serverfault frankensteining

Tags: bug, serverfault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Issues with the sidebar ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60162/issues-with-the-sidebar-ads)

This keeps happening on-and-off on SF for the last 30 minutes or so. I assume it's a known issue, just wanted to be sure.

[alt text http://www.41085.org/frank.png](http://www.41085.org/frank.png)

Keep getting the SO favicon with careers embedded on the sidebar

Comment: On inspection it actually looks like the SF Careers ad banner is giving a 500 error instead of the correct HTML, and **its** favicon is overriding the SF one.